# Implementing minibatch in input fn

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm currently experimenting with the new high level tf.contrib.learn APIs in Tensorflow by porting over features from the inception-v3 retrain script from this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining):

May I know how do I replicate the minibatch sampling every iteration for both validation and training inputs as seen in the original retrain.py?

Currently I tried using tf.train.shuffle_batch in the input_fn function but not I'm not certain that it works.

Some code snippet for clarity

```
def train_input_fn():
    # Get a batch of input bottleneck values, either calculated fresh every
    # time with distortions applied, or from the cache stored on disk.
    if do_distort_images:
        (train_bottleneck_outputs, train_ground_truths) = get_random_distorted_bottlenecks(
                sess, image_lists, -1, 'training',
                FLAGS.image_dir, distorted_jpeg_data_tensor,
                distorted_image_tensor, resized_image_tensor, bottleneck_tensor)
    else:
        (train_bottleneck_outputs, train_ground_truths, _) = get_random_cached_bottlenecks(
                sess, image_lists, -1, 'training',
                FLAGS.bottleneck_dir, FLAGS.image_dir, jpeg_data_tensor,
                bottleneck_tensor)
    return tf.train.shuffle_batch([tf.constant(train_bottleneck_outputs),
                                     tf.constant(train_ground_truths)],
                                      batch_size=FLAGS.train_batch_size, capacity=1100,
                                      min_after_dequeue=1000, enqueue_many=True, num_threads=2)
```

Comment: Did you provide the correct link to the tutorial?

Comment: Ohh right I posted the wrong link. Thanks for the heads-up